# Product flavour not using correct drawable res

Tags: android, vector, drawable, android-productflavors

I have a product flavour and I'm naming it the same resource name so that when it's built, it will use the correct image.

The folder structures look something like:

`main/res/drawable-xhdpi/image.png` (etc. has hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi)

`flavour/res/drawable/image.xml` (a vector)

So they have the same names. There are PNG versions in the `main` sourceset and a vector version in the `flavour`.

I defined my image resource to be `R.drawable.image` so that they can switch depending on flavour. When I run my `flavour` build, instead I get images related to the `main` build and not the vector.

Anyone know what's going wrong here?

I've tried to put the vector image with a different filename and used that instead and it works, but ideally I want to use the same `id res` so that it just switches based on flavour.

I'm using it in an `Image` composable

```
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.image),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 4.dp),
        )
```

Comment: "There are PNG versions in the main sourceset and a vector version in the flavour." -  image.png is present in main `drawable-xhdpi` , and not in flavor in `drwable-xhdpi`(only present in `drawable`) . So when rendering the image from `xhdpi` it picks up  `main res` version and not the flavor. Try using png images for flavor or xml image for the main

Comment: Hmm yes that seems about right. Kind of annoying I have to change it to one or the other. Thanks.